SELECT adding row with custom text to query
I would like to join multiple Tables add a dummy leading row additionally to my SELECT query with some custom Text for each queried field.
Is there a way to do that?
(bla is the custom text in the example)
Like
SELECT table1.x, table2.y, table3.z
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON ...
LEFT JOIN table3
ON ...

To have something like:
| table1.x | table2.y | table3.z | 
| bla      | blabla   | blab     |
| Result   | Result   | Result   |
| Result   | Result   | Result   |


Only if all of those columns are already textual-typed (char, nvarchar, text, etc) - if they're int or date then no. But this is a bad idea anyway - please tell us why you want to do this...

If it's because you want to attach custom metadata to each column, then I suggest looking at your RDBMS' feature-set for options. For example, in T-SQL (for MSSQL), you can use benign RAISERROR ... NOWAIT (sic) events as a side-channel for text and other metadata - or perhaps a secondary resultset.

I want actually a custom row based on conditions depending what is in the results. I'm trying to create a custom report.

SQL is not a report-generation-language, so you're going to run into problems if you do that...

Use your application to add such rows, this functionality has absolutely nothing to do with SQL.

Use UNION ALL add a custom header line
SELECT x,y,z FROM
(
    SELECT 'bla' as x,'blabla' as y,'blab' as z, 0 as SortOrder  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT table1.x, table2.y, table3.z, (1 or some other field) as SortOrder
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON ...
    LEFT JOIN table3
    ON ...
) t
ORDER BY SortOrder


@Jonas Metzler Thanks. I added the missing alias.

@Jonas Metzler good point. I added SortOrder as an option to overcome this issue.

Ok, after all the changes you have done on your query, it might now produce the expected result with some luck (assuming all data types match). Tomorrow, it might not. The big question is still why to do this in SQL.

@Jonas Metzler I agree this is a terrible idea. antalj should consider better options.

thank you all for your answers. I will try to do some more research, and find a better idea, however I'm not very experienced in the tool and database I'm using
